# How can i apply JoltTransformation on the hole json flowfile without splitting it?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

The next flow file is an ***InvoqueHTTP*** response:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Rolf",
    "sur_name": "ramsfl"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jose",
    "sur_name": "maxim"
  },
  {
    "name": "Andrei",
    "sur_name": "alexo"
  }
]
```

I wanted to use JoltTransformation instead of (***ReplaceText*** to find the **`"_"`** and change it by *emptystring*) ***ReplaceText*** is not the needed solution.

I created this ***JoltTransformation***:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
    "name":"name",
    "sur_name":"surname"
    }
  }
]
```

This jolttransformation solves the problem well but if the flowfile is splitted , if i pass it as it is it gives null.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JoltTransformRecord` processor:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Jolt Transformation DSL`: `Chain`
- `Jolt Specification`:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*_*": "[&1].&(0,1)&(0,2)",
        "*": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output Json**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Rolf",
    "surname": "ramsfl"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jose",
    "surname": "maxim"
  },
  {
    "name": "Andrei",
    "surname": "alexo"
  }
]
```

Comment: i have a lot of modification that i should apply , i know your solution and doesn't solve the problem please read again my question, is how to apply the jolttransformation like i did on the hole flowfile, without splitting it, using my solution not yours .

Answer (score 0):

Is this spec resolving your issue :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name",
        "sur_name": "[&1].surname"
      }
    }
  }
]
```